# Mining pools repayment in a coinbase tx

Tags: mining-pools, coinbase-transaction

Is it possible to add more outputs than one to the coinbase transaction? And if it is, can miners use them to repay users for renting hash to the pool?
I think in this case they know who to pay and this could prevent blocks from being found almost instantly and empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to add more outputs in coinbase transaction.

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/103612

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Or flag the question as a duplicate, once you have enough reputation.